# How to download files to app from app folder without linking an account via Dropbox API?

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

How do you automatically download a file from Dropbox, say a .txt or .pdf file, from the app folder (Dropbox) programmatically without having the user link their account and do it manually? Is this even possible? The goal is to eventually display the file in the app.

Edit: I would like to clarify that the file would NOT be the user's. I am just trying to get my OWN file from the app's folder which is located under the developer's Dropbox AKA me.

Edit 2: I will be updating this file, which is why I'm storing it remotely on Dropbox. (to avoid having to repeatedly update the whole app) The purpose is to simply use my Dropbox as a database to retrieve this file from.

Comment: From a security point of view, there better not be a way to do this.

Comment: I'm not suggesting downloading a file from the user's Dropbox. That would not be okay at all. The file would be from the app's Dropbox folder. (A folder under the account of the developer AKA me)

Comment: So, you want people to use your app, that gets a file from your drop box? Im guessing you would be updating that file and using it kinda like you would a database?

Comment: Pretty much. I guess I should add that to my post as well. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It would think it's possible, I could be wrong. I don't know the dropbox API, but you could just store your username/password and whatever else you need to login to dropbox, in your program in a NSArray or an object if you wanna be fancy. Then just use that when you want to get the file. I can't imagine storing it in the app being safe tho.

Comment: I'm also guessing it would go in the viewDidLoad section. try it out, you're really not gonna get explanations on this site unless you show what you tried to do.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/204110983-Is-linking-necessary-to-download-files- ]